# Trying to understand why adjectives do not refer

Tags: grammar, inflection, nouns, adjectives

[**Question rewritten and retitled, now that I have a better understanding of what I didn't understand, due to comments**]

This is probably information I could find on the Internet elsewhere, but I am hoping someone here can explain the difference in a sort of informal way that jibes.

Consider *bean*. How are 'soup of beans', 'bean soup', and 'beany soup' fundamentally different? As I now understand it, *beany* predicates, whereas *beans* in 'of beans' refers.

It seems to me that the word *beany* would refer to the set of 'beany things', and *soup* would limit this set to 'beany things' that are also 'soup'.

*Beans* in 'soup of beans' would refer to the set of things that are actually beans (in plural), and 'soup' would limit this to the those that are also 'soup'.

I understand these sets are different, but I still don't quite get it. If they can really be compared at all, what is the fundamental *difference* between reference and predication here? Why can't adjectives be said to refer?

Comment: What exactly is the question you're trying to ask?

Comment: Nope.  Doesn't make sense.  Adjectives don't refer; they predicate.

Comment: @GregLee Okay, that seems to be the crux of this. I still see a set of items associated wih an adjective, but it's a broader and fuzzier set, but somehow more formal. Perhaps I didn't think this through very well. Make it an answer, add the essence of the difference, and I'll accept. Sorry for the probably noob question.

Comment: Amazing that someone can answer my question with some standard grammatical jargon and get an upvote, while another can state that I made no inquiry and get an upvote.

Comment: @dwn They both said the question doesn't make much sense. The only part that's super simple to understand is the title, and as Greg said, adjectives don't refer.

Comment: Noun phrases can occupy argument positions of predicates and in that sense refer to the things that the predicates predicate something of.  Adjectives don't occupy argument positions (at least not typically).  Predicate noun phrases also predicate and do not refer.  Noun phrases with common nouns in argument position also predicate something of the arguments they refer to.  These are just conventions of predicate logic, so far as I know, and have nothing to do with linguistic analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am considering this answered by a comment:

> Noun phrases can occupy argument positions of predicates and in that sense refer to the things that the predicates predicate something of. Adjectives don't occupy argument positions (at least not typically). Predicate noun phrases also predicate and do not refer. Noun phrases with common nouns in argument position also predicate something of the arguments they refer to. These are just conventions of predicate logic, so far as I know, and have nothing to do with linguistic analysis. –  Greg Lee

If you have anything to add, please feel free to do so.

Answer (score 0):

To me the problem seems to be a bit theoretical or belonging to the philosophical field of logic. Perhaps part of your problems would be solved if you called "bean" 
in "bean soup" a noun used as compound element of a noun, and not an adjective. By the way "beany" is not registered as a word in Longman's Dictionary of Contemporary English.